# Unable to disable MDM on macbook pro with Ventura

Tags: macbook-pro, ventura, mdm, automated-device-enrollment

My son bought this Macbook from some guy for cheap. Did'nt bother to check if he can login and use it.
I wiped the macbook clean. And installed ventura, after it asked for wifi and country name, it goes into the MDM menu.
I turned ON macbook with CMD+R, went into terminal and did
echo "0.0.0.0 iprofiles.apple.com" >> /etc/hosts
Made sure the command succeeded by cat /etc/hosts. Exit from terminal. Now back in the mac recovery menu and choose 'install MacOS', it does its thing for 50 minutes and after a few apple logo's, it takes me back to the MDM and hangs. The editing of /etc/hosts file to block iprofiles.apple.com is not sticking after reboot. Please help me in completing install of MacOS after bypassing the MDM.

Comment: Why are you trying to bypass the MDM? I'm sure it's here for a reason.

Comment: I am trying to bypass it because I am not associated with the company that is shown on the MDM screen. My son purchased this without knowing that it will be impossible to reset and use. Returning it is not an option

Comment: Only the original owners can release it, or Apple with proof of ownership.